# NameError in coin flip program

Tags: python, python-2.7

This is my code for a simple coin flip program. The only issue is that `h` and `t` are not defined, even though I want those to be the `userChoice` variable. 
What am I missing or not doing right?

```
class Heads_or_Tails:
    import random

    print("Enter 'h' for Heads and 't' for Tails.")
    userChoice = raw_input()
    userChoice = raw_input()

    try:
        input("Press Enter to see result.")
    except SyntaxError:
        pass

    a = 1
    b = 2

    machineChoice = random.randrange(1, 2, 2)

    if(machineChoice == a):
        if(userChoice == h):
            print("You win!")
        elif(userChoice == t):
            print("You lose.")
        else:
            pass
    if(machineChoice == b):
        if(userChoice == h):
            print("You lose.")
        if(userChoice == t):
            print("You win!")
        else:
            pass

    try:
        input("Press Enter to exit.")
    except SyntaxError:
        pass
```

Comment: `if(userChoice == h):` should be `if userChoice == 'h':`

Comment: I just tried this and my program did not display any result. Here is the result...Enter 'h' for Heads and 't' for Tails.
h

Press Enter to see result.
Press Enter to exit.
>>>

Comment: Whoops! I have userChoice = raw_input twice. Now I will retry that suggestion of yours.

Comment: The final code that made this work was 134 chars too long. I change "random.randrange(1, 2, 2)" to "random.randint(a, b)" and removed one of the "userChoice = raw_input()" commands. Thank you so much!

Comment: Also there is no reason for that to be in a `class`, and `import` should be at the start of the script.

Comment: Noted. Why should it not be in a class though? I have some Java experience and when I did Java programs, we always had to make a class declaration. Just asking.

Comment: [Python is not Java](http://dirtsimple.org/2004/12/python-is-not-java.html); you don't need to put everything in a class, and *shouldn't* when a function will suffice (and you're not actually saving state or creating instances).

Comment: Oh, ok. Can you also help me re-execute this code? For instance: The user got there answer, and they want to play again without re-running the program, how can I do this?

Comment: With a `while` loop... Perhaps go and follow a tutorial, e.g. https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html

Comment: Thank you! Sorry about the long discussion in the comments. I only have '1' reputation.

Comment: I followed your while loop advice with this "print("Would you like to use this program?")  --> userAnswer = raw_
input()  --> and the rest of the code from before is inside this "while(userAnswer != 'no')". It tells me that on this line there is a SyntaxError. Is there something missing?

Comment: Indentation is important in Python, and it is therefore unreadable in comments. Again, please review the tutorial - if you're getting a `SyntaxError` then yes, something is missing, likely a colon or closing parenthesis.